# Integrating the Schechter function...

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

I'm trying to integrate this equation over all L.

I really have no idea where to start for some reason :S

$$\phi(L)dL=\phi_0\left(\dfrac L{L\star}\right)^\alpha\exp\left(-\dfrac L{L\star}\right)\dfrac{dL}{L\star}.$$

According to the internet I should end up with this:

$$\int_0^\infty L\phi d=\phi_0L_\star\Gamma(\alpha+2)$$

But I can't understand why

Comment: don't know, haven't been told so I guess it doesn't matter

Comment: @tired: $*$ is an asterisk; $\star$ is a `\star`.

Comment: This is essentially the definition of the Gamma function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comment the integral is easy to solve in terms of the Gamma function:

Rescale $L/L\star=x$, $(L\star)dx=L$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty}\phi_0\left(\frac{L}{L\star}\right)^{\alpha}e^{-\frac{L}{L\star}}\frac{dL}{L\star}=(\phi_0L\star)\int_0^{\infty}t^{\alpha+1}e^{-x}dx=\phi_0(L\star)\Gamma(\alpha+2)
\end{align}

Comment: A neat answer. (+1)!